# CSS3 FLEXBOX not correct working Chrome (FF - OK)

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Some structure working good in FF, but Chrome is NOT.

Stack snippet

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%!important; width: 100%!important;
    margin: 0!important; padding: 0!important;
}

.x {display: flex; flex-direction: column; height: 100%; width: 100%;}
    .x-header {background-color: silver;}
    .x-body {flex: 1 1 auto; overflow-y: auto;}

/* CONTENT WITH 2 COLUMNS */
.x-structure-2-columns {display: flex; flex-direction: row; height: 100%; width: 100%;}
    .x-structure-2-columns-left {background-color: lightgreen; width: 100px;}
    .x-structure-2-columns-right {display: flex; flex: 1 1 auto; overflow-y: auto; flex-direction: column;}
        .x-structure-2-columns-right-header {background: yellow;}
        .x-structure-2-columns-right-body {flex: 1 1 auto; overflow-y: auto; min-height: 0px; background: pink;}
```

```html
<div class="x">
    <div class="x-header">This is a header</div>
    <div class="x-body">
        <div class="x-structure-2-columns">
            <div class="x-structure-2-columns-left">
                LEFT
            </div>
            <div class="x-structure-2-columns-right">
                <div class="x-structure-2-columns-right-header">SUB NAVIGATION</div>
                <div class="x-structure-2-columns-right-body"><p>123<br>345<br>678</p><p>123<br>345<br>678</p><p>123<br>345<br>678</p><p>123<br>345<br>678</p><p>123<br>345<br>678</p><p>123<br>345<br>678</p><p>123<br>345<br>678</p><p>123<br>345<br>678</p><p>123<br>345<br>678</p><p>123<br>345<br>678</p><p>123<br>345<br>678</p><p>123<br>345<br>678</p><p>123<br>345<br>678</p><p>123<br>345<br>678</p><p>123<br>345<br>678</p><p>123<br>345<br>678</p><p>123<br>345<br>678</p><p>123<br>345<br>678</p><p>123<br>345<br>678</p><p>123<br>345<br>678</p><p>123<br>345<br>678</p><p>123<br>345<br>678</p><p>123<br>345<br>678</p><p>123<br>345<br>678</p><p>123<br>345<br>678</p><p>123<br>345<br>678</p><p>123<br>345<br>678</p><p>123<br>345<br>678</p><p>123<br>345<br>678</p><p>123<br>345<br>678</p></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

2 columns must be fixed, but they are not in Chrome.

Here is also a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q28v4z05/

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you've used `height: 100%`, combined with partial nested Flexbox.

That is not recommended, as e.g. a flex item normally use *flex-grow* or *align-items* to fill a given height/width of its parent, and with that, does not have a height set. So when a child of a flex item gets one, using percent, it will in most cases resolve to `auto` and cause it all to not work properly.

Instead use Flexbox all the way.

The main fix here is to reset `min-height`'s default `auto` to `0` on `x`, allowing it to be smaller than its content, combined with adding `display: flex`, making it a flex container.

With this we can remove the `height: 100%` on `.x-structure-2-columns` and let Flexbox take care of the space distribution.

*Note, instead of `min-height: 0`, one can use `overflow` (with a value other than `visible`), as you did in some place with `overflow-y: auto;`, though the `min-height` is more proper when it comes to readability, unless one need e.g. a scrollbar, like on the `x-structure-2-columns-right-body`.*

*I also cleaned up some properties, that is either not needed or had its default value.*

*Below sample is tested with success on the lastest version of Chrome, Firefox, Edge, and IE11.*

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x9oggzxa/2/)

Stack snippet

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.x {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.x-header {
  background-color: silver;
}

.x-body {
  flex: 1;
  min-height: 0;                          /*  added  */
  display: flex;                          /*  added  */
}


/* CONTENT WITH 2 COLUMNS */
.x-structure-2-columns {
  flex: 1;                                /*  fill width  */
  display: flex;
}

.x-structure-2-columns-left {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  width: 100px;
}

.x-structure-2-columns-right {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.x-structure-2-columns-right-header {
  background: yellow;
}

.x-structure-2-columns-right-body {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="x">
  <div class="x-header">This is a header</div>
  <div class="x-body">
    <div class="x-structure-2-columns">
      <div class="x-structure-2-columns-left">
        LEFT
      </div>
      <div class="x-structure-2-columns-right">
        <div class="x-structure-2-columns-right-header">SUB NAVIGATION</div>
        <div class="x-structure-2-columns-right-body">
          <p>123
            <br>345
            <br>678</p>
          <p>123
            <br>345
            <br>678</p>
          <p>123
            <br>345
            <br>678</p>
          <p>123
            <br>345
            <br>678</p>
          <p>123
            <br>345
            <br>678</p>
          <p>123
            <br>345
            <br>678</p>
          <p>123
            <br>345
            <br>678</p>
          <p>123
            <br>345
            <br>678</p>
          <p>123
            <br>345
            <br>678</p>
          <p>123
            <br>345
            <br>678</p>
          <p>123
            <br>345
            <br>678</p>
          <p>123
            <br>345
            <br>678</p>
          <p>123
            <br>345
            <br>678</p>
          <p>123
            <br>345
            <br>678</p>
          <p>123
            <br>345
            <br>678</p>
          <p>123
            <br>345
            <br>678</p>
          <p>123
            <br>345
            <br>678</p>
          <p>123
            <br>345
            <br>678</p>
          <p>123
            <br>345
            <br>678</p>
          <p>123
            <br>345
            <br>678</p>
          <p>123
            <br>345
            <br>678</p>
          <p>123
            <br>345
            <br>678</p>
          <p>123
            <br>345
            <br>678</p>
          <p>123
            <br>345
            <br>678</p>
          <p>123
            <br>345
            <br>678</p>
          <p>123
            <br>345
            <br>678</p>
          <p>123
            <br>345
            <br>678</p>
          <p>123
            <br>345
            <br>678</p>
          <p>123
            <br>345
            <br>678</p>
          <p>123
            <br>345
            <br>678</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thx a lot! Working perfect!